# IFS statement with multiple nested QUERY functions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

With a fair amount of help from SO folks, I managed to put together about 15 `QUERY` tabs used to extract necessary data for reporting.

In order to make it tidy, I'd like to enclose all these queries in an `IFS` statement referring to a `Data Validation` cell and run the `QUERY` by simply changing the value from the validation cell.

I managed to get it running with no errors, however, I get a single cell output.

What I am using for this is:

```
=IFS('Validation'!$A$1 = "Giberish",

              {QUERY('All'!$A$5:$AP, 
                     "SELECT AJ, '" & IDBlah & "', 'Blah' 
                       WHERE AJ IS NOT NULL 
                       LABEL '" & IDBlah & "' 'ID', 
                             'Blah'           'BlahBlahBlah'",1)},

     'Validation'!$A$1 = "GiberishGiberish",

              {QUERY('All'!$A$5:$AP,
                     "SELECT AJ, 'WCaa', 'Blah'
                       WHERE AJ IS NOT NULL
                      LABEL 'WCaa'            'BlahBlah',
                            'Blah'            'BlahBlahBlah'",1);
               QUERY('Upload'!$A$2:$AL,
                     "SELECT A, 'WCaa', 'Blah'
                       WHERE A IS NOT NULL
                      LABEL 'WCaa'              '',
                            'Blah'              ''",0)} )
```

I tried to enclose it all in an `ARRAYFORMULA`, but I get the same single cell output, with no error.

[image: Output]

What is the correct approach?

Let me know if you need dummy data, but have in mind that I have corporate security policies that restrict me from sharing **any** sheet to anyone outside of the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use `IF` instead of `IFS` like:

```
=IF(Validation!$A$1 = "Giberish", {QUERY(All!$A$5:$AP, 
                                   "SELECT AJ,'"&IDBlah&"','Blah' 
                                    WHERE AJ IS NOT NULL 
                                    LABEL '"&IDBlah&"''ID','Blah''BlahBlahBlah'",1)},

 IF(Validation!$A$1 = "GiberishGiberish", {QUERY(All!$A$5:$AP,
                                           "SELECT AJ,'WCaa','Blah'
                                            WHERE AJ IS NOT NULL
                                            LABEL 'WCaa''BlahBlah','Blah''BlahBlahBlah'",1);
                                           QUERY(Upload!$A$2:$AL,
                                           "SELECT A, 'WCaa','Blah'
                                            WHERE A IS NOT NULL
                                            LABEL 'WCaa''','Blah'''",0)}, ))
```

when `IFS` is in a combination of `ARRAYFORMULA` it gains a special skill which requires an array to be inputted in order to output an array again.

**https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/124685/186471**

Comment: Cheers! Very helpful!